# Opencart 2.x Undefined Index product.php

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to figure out an issue with an undefined index error when a product is saved or edited.

I have created a new entry in the product table in the database called disable_cart which is set to int(1) and has a default value of 0.

On the product_form.tpl it is simply a checkbox.

```
    <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="checkbox">
                 <label>
                  <?php if ($disable_cart) { ?>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="disable_cart" value="1" checked="checked" id="input-disable_cart" />
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="disable_cart" value="1" id="input-disable_cart" />
                  <?php } ?>
                  &nbsp; </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The code in the product controller

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['disable_cart'])) {
        $data['disable_cart'] = $this->request->post['disable_cart'];
    } elseif (!empty($product_info['disable_cart'])) {
        $data['disable_cart'] = $product_info['disable_cart'];
    } else {
        $data['disable_cart'] = 0;
    }
```

And the model in the addProduct() function

```
public function addProduct($data) {
    $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.product.add', $data);

    . "', disable_cart = '" . (int)$data['disable_cart'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

Same in the editProduct() function. It works fine on my localhost but only works on the dev server if the checkbox is ticked otherwise I get the following error

```
Undefined index: disable_cart in /admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 134Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /admin/index.php:80) in /system/library/response.php on line 12
```

Can't figure out the issue, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

edit: The value does save in the DB but it still throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that **an unchecked Checkbox will not be sent through `post`**

1. So there is no `post['disable_cart']`.
2. When you post a new product or make an edit, this part of the code is called:

   ```
   if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
           $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($this->request->post);
   ```

**`$data['disable_cart']` has not been defined at all**. so the `addProduct` function will throw an exception.

**The solution** is to add this line of code:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
   // add this line to `add` and to `edit`
   if(!isset($this->request->post['disable_cart'])) $this->request->post['disable_cart'] = 0;

   $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($this->request->post); 
...
```

As for the warning, it is simply saying that you have a premature output due to the error being thrown.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response,

I should have posted the full code, that code is within the getForm() function which is called into the add() and edit() functions $this->getForm();

Comment: I made a lot of assumptions regarding your code and I am sorry for that. 1/Could you please show me what line 134 is about?.  2/Is it the same error when you add and when you edit (same line)?.  3/ Did you use a modification engine (`vqMod` or `ocMod`)?

Comment: No need to apologise, I appreciate your help.

1)  is the editProduct() function `"', disable_cart = '" . (int)$data['disable_cart'] . "',`

2) Yes it is not working for either add or edit

3) No it is directly in the relative files

As I said it works fine on my localhost but throws the error on the development server(But still saves the value).

Comment: **I think I found your problem:** 1) An unchecked Checkbox will not be sent through `post['disable_cart']` so **there is no $data['disable_cart']**.  2) When you post a new product or make an edit, this part of the code is called: `if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {$this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($this->request->post);...}`. there is no way  $data['disable_cart'] has been set. so the `addProduct` function will throw an exception. Please see edited answer

Comment: Hi,

I have added the line to the controllers add and edit functions but the exception is still being thrown.

Comment: Sorry! typo! I wrote `$data['disable_cart'] = 0;`, it should be `$this->request->post['disable_cart'] = 0;` see edited answer :)

Comment: No problem, unfortunately it still hasn't worked but I have come across a solution within the model file ` `disable_cart` = '" . (isset($data['disable_cart']) ? (int)$data['disable_cart'] : 0)`

I'm not sure why your answer didn't work because it makes logical sens e.

Thanks a million for your help

Comment: Good thinking! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi, and sorry to bother you again, but if you could accept my answer that would help me help other people, since most of OC don't bother accepting answers leaving me with limited privileges and thus limited abilities to help others :)